# How to calculate the difference in days based on what is found in different date columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table that has a datetime which corresponds to different statuses: clicked, claimed and bought for each user.

I collapse the records of each user and put each datetime corresponding to each status in their own column: clicked_date, claimed_date, and bought_date. I also have a deadline_date.

Now I need another column that calculates the number of days to the deadline date. The new column (number_days) should always subtract deadline_date minus clicked_date. However, if clicked_date is set to "2999-12-31' then it should subtract deadline_date minus claimed_date. If clicked_date is set to "2999-12-31' and claimed_date is set to = '299-12-31' then it should subtract deadline_date minus bought_date. And If clicked_date is set to "2999-12-31' and claimed_date is set to "2999-12-31' and bought_date is set to "2999-12-31' OR deadline_date = '/N' then it should be 0.

[image]

[image]

```
In the examples above,
The first record should be (deadline_date - bought_date)
The second record should be (deadline_date - clicked_date) 
The third record should be 0.
The fourth record should be (deadline_date - claimed_date)
The fifth record should be (deadline_date - claimed_date) 
The fifth record should be (deadline_date - clicked_date)
```

I am having trouble formulating this query. Does anyone know how I can calculate the number of days depending on what is found in each of the three different date columns for clicked, claimed and bought?

I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
select 
user,
(array_agg(STATUS) within group(order by UPDATED_AT_DATETIME desc)[0])::varchar as last_status,
   coalesce(max(case when STATUS = 'clicked'  THEN UPDATED_AT_DATETIME END),'2999-12-31'::datetime) as clicked_date,
   coalesce(max(case when STATUS = 'claimed'   THEN UPDATED_AT_DATETIME END),'2999-12-31'::datetime) as claimed_date,
   coalesce(max(case when STATUS = 'bought' THEN ACCOUNT_REWARD_UPDATED_AT_DATETIME END),'2999-12-31'::datetime) as bought_date,
   **case when CLICKED_DATE <> '2999-12-31 00:00:00.000' then DATEDIFF('days', TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(clicked_date) ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(DEADLINE_DATETIME))
   when claimed_date <> '2999-12-31 00:00:00.000' then DATEDIFF('days', TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(claimed_date) ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(DEADLINE_DATETIME))
   when bought_date <> '2999-12-31 00:00:00.000' then DATEDIFF('days', TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(bought_date) ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(DEADLINE_DATETIME))
   END as number_days**
from TBL_A a
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Those rules can be written also directly like:

```
SELECT 
    clicked_date,
    claimed_date,
    bought_date,
    deadline_date,
    CASE
        WHEN clicked_date != "2999-12-31" THEN datediff(day,deadline_date,  clicked_date)
        WHEN clicked_date = "2999-12-31" THEN datediff(day, deadline_date, claimed_date)
        WHEN clicked_date = "2999-12-31" AND claimed_date = "2999-12-31" THEN datediff(day, deadline_date, bought_date)
        WHEN clicked_date = "2999-12-31" AND claimed_date = "2999-12-31" AND bought_date = "2999-12-31" THEN 0
        WHEN deadline_date = "/N" THEN 0
    END AS number_days
FROM table;
```

BUT, the 3rd and 4th rules are more restrictive of the 2nd rule, so need to be placed prior so they trigger, thus the code you want is like so:

```
SELECT 
    clicked_date,
    claimed_date,
    bought_date,
    deadline_date,
    CASE
        WHEN clicked_date != "2999-12-31" THEN datediff(day,deadline_date,  clicked_date)
        WHEN clicked_date = "2999-12-31" AND claimed_date = "2999-12-31" AND bought_date = "2999-12-31" THEN 0
        WHEN clicked_date = "2999-12-31" AND claimed_date = "2999-12-31" THEN datediff(day, deadline_date, bought_date)
        WHEN clicked_date = "2999-12-31" THEN datediff(day, deadline_date, claimed_date)
        WHEN deadline_date = "/N" THEN 0
    END AS number_days
FROM table;
```

OR you can put the exlusions in if you want to be explicit:

```
SELECT 
    clicked_date,
    claimed_date,
    bought_date,
    deadline_date,
    CASE
        WHEN clicked_date != "2999-12-31" 
            THEN datediff(day,deadline_date,  clicked_date)
        WHEN clicked_date = "2999-12-31" AND claimed_date != "2999-12-31" AND bought_date != "2999-12-31" 
            THEN datediff(day, deadline_date, claimed_date)
        WHEN clicked_date = "2999-12-31" AND claimed_date = "2999-12-31" AND bought_date != "2999-12-31" 
            THEN datediff(day, deadline_date, bought_date)
        WHEN clicked_date = "2999-12-31" AND claimed_date = "2999-12-31" AND bought_date = "2999-12-31" 
            THEN 0
        WHEN deadline_date = "/N" 
            THEN 0
    END AS number_days
FROM table;
```

Now the above will work if your "dates" are DATES but if they are just strings, as implied by the "/N" you will need to CAST/Parse those strings into dates. Like:

```
SELECT 
    clicked_date,
    claimed_date,
    bought_date,
    deadline_date,
    CASE
        WHEN clicked_date != "2999-12-31" 
            THEN datediff(day,deadline_date::date,  clicked_date::date)
        WHEN clicked_date = "2999-12-31" AND claimed_date != "2999-12-31" AND bought_date != "2999-12-31" 
            THEN datediff(day, deadline_date::date, claimed_date::date)
        WHEN clicked_date = "2999-12-31" AND claimed_date = "2999-12-31" AND bought_date != "2999-12-31" 
            THEN datediff(day, deadline_date::date, bought_date::date)
        WHEN clicked_date = "2999-12-31" AND claimed_date = "2999-12-31" AND bought_date = "2999-12-31" 
            THEN 0
        WHEN deadline_date = "/N" 
            THEN 0
    END AS number_days
FROM table;
```